mpmath and mathmatica discrepancy in output

edited because my main issue lies with incorrect results from mp.math.

I need to eventually do very precise calculations with complex numbers, which is why I am trying to use the mp module from mp.math. (Admittedly I have read the mp math documentation, but am new to it) After running into incorrect answers, I traced my issue back to the fact that when I do a calculation on mpmath (see bellow) I get a different result than when I do the same with mathematica. Could someone help me figure out what I am doing wrong?
mp.math:
from mpmath import mp
mp.dps = 300;
mp.exp(mp.fmul(mp.mpf(str(-64)),mp.mpf(str(.2))))
Output: mpf('0.00000276077257203720079298503881941442964716356235195837374540868148586730700359076564381986686089035467149986363953794158687758910992470828322377833660309685941797430472579604476223424097045454723393291529826485166261076775808555479838036656035924269261878257522607849410841260713806720383331539818973042529')
mathmatica
SetPrecision[Exp[-64*.2], 300]
Output:
2.76077257203719864675777080631480231431851279921829700469970703125000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000*10^-6
I would expect the results to be the same, but by around the 20th decimal place they start to differ.

To get the full accuracy out of mpmath or Decimal, you have to exclusively use their provided data types for any values that aren't exactly representable in the standard Python types.  You lost the game the moment you wrote .2 as a float literal, as that's not a value that a float can actually have.

okay I understand thank you. So how can I input .2 into mp math to get accurate results?

I used x=mp.mpmathify(.2) to get the same answer as decimal, but I am not sure if either are correct. I compared to Mathematica but I get something different there too.

You need to pass such values as a string.  .2, as a float, actually has a value that's closer to 0.2000000000000000111.

but is that not what I did here? mp.exp(mp.fmul(mp.mpf(str(-64)),mp.mpf(str(.2))))

str(.2) isn't necessarily the same as ".2" - it happens to round correctly in this case (in some versions of Python, at least), but you can't count on that.

okay, thank you. I guess my issue is that I still get a result that differs from mathematica (2.76077257203719864675777080631480231431851279921829700469970703125000000000000*10^-6) so the mpmath result is still not accurate?

basically, I think mp.math is giving my nonsense after about the 20th decimal place.

In this case I think you appear to have found a bug in Mathematica or not asked the question of it in quite the right way. Its answer for exp(-12.8) doesn't look at all plausible to me with all those trailing zeroes.
When I throw the calculation at Julia and increase the precision sufficiently it agrees with the result that you obtained all the way when I increased precision to 1000 bits. I'm not sure of the implementation details of Julia's BigFloats but they have never let me down before.
julia> exp(-BigFloat(64)/BigFloat(5))

2.760772572037200792985038819414429647163562351958373745
408681485867307003590676e-06
julia> setprecision(BigFloat, 500)
500

julia> exp(-BigFloat(64)/BigFloat(5))

2.7607725720372007929850388194144296471635623519583737454086814858673070035907656438198668608903546714998636395379415868775891099247082832237783366030938e-06
julia> setprecision(BigFloat, 1000)
1000

julia> exp(-BigFloat(64)/BigFloat(5))

2.76077257203720079298503881941442964716356235195837374540868148586730700359076564381986686089035467149986363953794158687758910992470828322377833660309685941797430472579604476223424097045454723393291529826485166261076775808555479838036656035924269261878257522607849410841260713806720383331539818973042529e-06
log(BigFloat("2.76077257203720079298503881941442964716356235195837374540868148586730700359076564381986686089035467149986363953794158687758910992470828322377833660309685941797430472579604476223424097045454723393291529826485166261076775808555479838036656035924269261878257522607849410841260713806720383331539818973042529e-06"))
-12.8000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003
Taking the log of the Mathematica answer in Julia it is clear that Mathematica has computed exp using standard 64bit double arithmetic. Oops!
julia> log(BigFloat("2.76077257203719864675777080631480231431851279921829700469970703125000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000e-6"))

-12.8000000000000007774009673058214261052537582953257100770542758344316669794447948750058707481330343868028670327576657852816894936980836750044670968536044806438802211617596023783929373187330881370009468791968179640611989465169433207621738713056795607656520114787722487328419418068321396252206120875122593
I think your answers from mpmath are in fact entirely correct and Mathematica is giving you misleading and incorrect answers (looking suspiciously like 64bit double 1/2^N truncated). PS Sorry about the formatting above. I don't seem to be able to indent the very long output lines (and breaking them up is too error prone)
